# Make CSS focus outline easier to see in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, accessibility, outline

I am trying to utilize tab navigation on a website. When it surrounds images, the default outline in Chrome can be very light, and thus hard to see.

I've played around with the possible values for the CSS `outline` property, but none of them have a pleasant "glow" like the default outline, the width of which I cannot seem to control, even with `outline-width`.

I've managed to emulate "a more obvious outline" with a box shadow:

```
*:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px blue;
  position: relative;
}
```

However, this solution has two problems:

1. The elements might need special positioning so that the "outline" will
   appear above adjacent following elements in the document (hence
   `position: relative`), which won't work in the general case, since
   inevitably some element is going to need to be `position: absolute`,
   etc.
2. An "outline" this obvious would be an offensive default for
   mouse users.

Therefore, I'd like to know if there is a browser setting to make the outline easier for me to see, and that (preferably) won't interfere with the page's styles.

Comment: Have you considered using `outline-style`?

Comment: It could be a last-resort option. All `outline-style` values, besides the default, produce rigid, ugly edges in Chrome - though they would make elements easier to see, and not interfere with other styles.

Answer (score 3):

This does not help you today, but CSS4 has a `:focusring` selector coming (though its name may change):

> `:focusring` only matches an element if the element is currently focused and a focus ring or other indicator should be drawn for that element. This is extremely useful for accessibility.

Essentially it is intended for keyboard use and cases where focus is programmatically moved to an item (something that might have `tabindex=-1` for example).

More info: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/pull/709

It is [based on `:-moz-focusring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-focusring).

As far as I know there is no pollyfill yet.

In the meantime, there are open issues with the browsers (sorry, cannot find them right now) to make default focus styles more visible.

But that also does not help you today.

I am aware that some folks use a screen reader, with focus indicators turned on, to see where they are on the page. This may be useful to you as a user, not an author. NVDA (free) allows this, for example, with a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

- **Chrome uses the "auto" outline style (`outline: auto 2px -webkit-focus-ring-color;`)**

**This, sadly, also overrides the default `outline-offset` value**

You can override this value only by both overriding the `outline` and `outline-offset` values:

```
outline: solid 2px rgba(77, 144, 254, 0.4);
outline-offset: 2px;
```

- The second solution, is to add a padding around each image:

For instance adding 2px white space between around the image:

```
a img {padding:2px}
```

With that solution, you don't override the default browser focus indicator

- Other solution, using dashed or dotted lines with semi transparent colors

Eg.:

```
a.img:focus {outline:dotted rgba(150,200,250,0.8) 2px}
<a href="..." class="img"><img ...

a.img:focus {outline:dashed rgba(150,200,250,0.5) 2px}
```